# private_pub/faye and nginx tcp -- 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: tcp, nginx, faye

So I got the tcp module for nginx all set up and am trying to use this with private_pub (faye) for websockets.  As of now I'm getting very slow loading from faye and a 502 Bad Gateway errors.  Everyone points towards configuring it like so:

I have this in my nginx.conf:

```
tcp {
  timeout 1d;
  websocket_read_timeout 1d;
  websocket_send_timeout 1d;

  upstream websockets {
    server 199.36.105.34:9292;
    check interval=300 rise=2 fall=5 timeout=1000;
  }

  server {
      listen 9200;
      server_name 2u.fm;

      timeout 43200000;
      websocket_connect_timeout 43200000;
      proxy_connect_timeout 43200000;

      so_keepalive on;
      tcp_nodelay on;

      websocket_pass websockets;
  }
```

I've tried every variation of that on the web.  I want to be able to hit it from my domain "2u.fm/faye" but the only way I can get that to work is to do a proxy inside my http block:

```
location /faye {                                                     
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;                         
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;      
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;                                  
  proxy_redirect off;

  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;                                  
  break;                                                             
}
```

Adding that makes it work at 2u.fm/faye but now I'm back at square one, still getting super slow responses and 502 Bad Gateway's.  Which I think makes sense as it's routing through http still and not directly to tcp.  I've tried hitting 199.36.105.34:9200 directly but I get no response.

Comment: Sounds like the backend is timing out, hence the 502.

Comment: But I can hit /faye directly and it loads instantly every time... I think this an issue with the socket not being accessed correctly (perhaps not setting up the tcp settings right).

Comment: I have just the same issue but I am not using websockets